# How do I set a Smoothing to grayscale in fonts.conf?

Tags: 10.04, fonts

In **gnome-appearance-properties** one can choose between none, grayscale and sub-pixel in the font Smoothing category. In **fonts.conf** one can have e.g.`<match target="font" > <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" > <const>unknown</const> </edit> </match>`. Unknown can have the values: unknown, rgb, bgr ,vrgb, vbgr, none . Which corresponds to grayscale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`none` represents grayscale (no colors are used for subpixel rendering).